# how can I change the parameter of N in following fmincon?

Tags: matlab, nested-function

I have to solve the following system of nonlinear algebraic equations via fmincon. the problem is that fmincon should try to find the best case when my condition (x(N)-7.6<=Tol) can be satisfied until then fmincon needs to run again. so we  need to use some loop to update the number of running fmincon and creating new initial condition either. but it seems there is no change of amount of N. how should I do?

```
 function [x]=runnested(x0,N)
 r=ones(4,1);
N=length(r);
Tol=0.001;
     for i=1:N
      x0=rand(5*N+13,1)
      options = optimset('Largescale','off','algorithm','interior-point','Display','iter');
      [x(i,:),fval,exitflag,output]=fmincon(@(x) norm(myfoctest(x)),x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],@myfoctest,options)
           while x(N)-7.61>Tol
             N=N+1;  
            end
     end
       function [C,Ceq]=myfoctest(x,N,r)
         C=[];
         r=ones(4,1); 
         N=length(r);
         Ceq=zeros(5*N+13,1);     
             for j=1:N-1     
          Ceq(j)=x(3*N+1+j)-3*N+j)-2*x(4*N+1+j)*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1+j))./(pi*sin(i1)*x(j)^2)
         Ceq(N+j)=x(4*N+1+j)-x(4*N+j)       
    Ceq(2*N+1+j)=x(3*N+1+j)*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1+j))+2*x(4*N+1+j)*Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1+j))./(pi*x(j)*sin(i1))
   Ceq(3*N+8+j)=x(j)-x(j+1)-Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1+j))
   Ceq(4*N+8+j)=Omeg0-x(j+1)+2*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1+j))./(pi*x(j)*sin(i1))
              end
Ceq(N)=x(5*N+10)-x(5*N+9)-x(3*N+2)  
Ceq(2*N)=x(5*N+12)-x(5*N+11)-x(4*N+2)
Ceq(2*N+1)=x(3*N+1)*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1))+2*x(4*N+1)*Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1))/(pi*V0*sin(i1))
Ceq(3*N+1)=1-x(5*N+9)*b1-x(5*N+10)*b1-x(5*N+11)*b2-x(5*N+12)*b2-x(5*N+8)*N*Ts/100-x(5*N+13)
Ceq(3*N+2)=-2*x(5*N+8)*x(5*N+2)
Ceq(3*N+3)=-2*x(5*N+9)*x(5*N+3)
Ceq(3*N+4)=-2*x(5*N+10)*x(5*N+4)
Ceq(3*N+5)=-2*x(5*N+11)*x(5*N+5)
Ceq(3*N+6)=-2*x(5*N+12)*x(5*N+6)
Ceq(3*N+7)=2*x(5*N+13)*cos(x(5*N+7))*sin(x(5*N+7))
Ceq(3*N+8)=V0-x(1)-Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1))
Ceq(4*N+8)=Omeg0-x(N+1)+2*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1))/(pi*V0*sin(i1))
Ceq(5*N+8)=-x(5*N+2)^2-N*Ts/100-N*Ts*x(3*N+1)/100
Ceq(5*N+9)=-x(5*N+3)^2-x(N)+a1+b1-b1*x(3*N+1)+7.61/100
Ceq(5*N+10)=-x(5*N+4)^2+x(N)+a1+b1-b1*x(3*N+1)-7.61/100
Ceq(5*N+11)=-x(5*N+5)^2-x(2*N)+a2+b2-b2*x(3*N+1)+0.35/100
Ceq(5*N+12)=-x(5*N+6)^2+x(2*N)+a2+b2-b2*x(3*N+1)-0.35/100
Ceq(5*N+13)=-(sin(x(5*N+7)))^2-x(5*N+1)
end
end
```

Comment: Firstly, please indent your code! Secondly, are you not getting an error when you call `fmincon` since your only pass `myfoctest` a single variable when it expects 3?

Comment: you're right....I fixed that in main code...but no change happened...it's stills running with no bug with no rise in N

Comment: I can paraphrase my question... how could we apply fmincon in our problem while the number of nonlinear constraints are not fixed?

Comment: Ali, you need to edit your question to (a) reflect that change and (b) INDENT!